# How to make user-input for Symbols case insensitive

Tags: python, sympy

I want to avoid **caps lock** errors in a *scypy* base script that I made.
 The script calculate partial derivatives

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import standard_transformations, \
x, y, z = symbols('x y z ', real=True)
transformations = (standard_transformations + (implicit_multiplication_application,)
self.eq1 = parse_expr(self.entry_5.get(), locals(), transformations=transformations)
self.dfx = diff(self.eq1, x)
self.dfy = diff(self.eq1, y)
self.dfz = diff(self.eq1, z)
```

It work fine for this example entry_5 is x ** 2 + y ** 2 + z ** 2

```
'Partial derivatives calculation:
 Partial der by X:  2*x
 Partial der by Y:  2*y
 Partial der by Z:  2*z
```

but now, I'm trying to add capital X,Y,Z with the same code:

```
.
.
.
x, y, z, X, Y, Z = symbols('x y z X Y Z', real=True)
.
.
.
```

now, entry_5 is- X ** 2 + y ** 2 + z ** 2 (capital x)
and the output is:

```
'Partial derivatives calculation:
 Partial der by X:  0
 Partial der by Y:  2*y
 Partial der by Z:  2*z
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. As far as SymPy is concerned symbols with names `'x'` and `'X'` are entirely independent. You can do `x = X = Symbol('x')` to use both `x` and `X` as Python variables corresponding to the same symbol if you want but `Symbol('x')` and `Symbol('X')` can not be used interchangeably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are wanting your input to be recast to lowercase so the derivatives that you hard coded always work you could either convert the input to lower case or, more safely, provide `locals` that remap the uppercase symbols of interest to lower case symbols. For clarity in the following I use `S` to sympify rather than the parser:

```
>>> S('x', {'x':'upper'})  # example showing you can replace 'x' with 'upper'
upper
>>> S('X', dict([(str(i), str(i).lower()) for i in symbols('X:Z')]))
x
```

In your code you will have to update your locals with the dict() that is being used in my example: `loc = locals(); loc.update(dict([(str(i), str(i).lower()) for i in symbols('X:Z')]))` and use `loc` instead of `locals()` in your code.